# Creating buttons dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating buttons dynamically using jQuery:

```
function createRefreshButton() {
  var $btn = $('<button/>', {
    text: 'Refresh Data',
    id: 'btn_refresh'
  });

  $($btn).on('click', function () {
    ClickRefresh()
  });

  return $btn;
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to change this code to something like this:

```
function createRefreshButton() {
  var $btn = $('<button/>', {
    text: 'Refresh Data',
    id: 'btn_refresh',
    onclick: 'ClickRefresh()'
  });
  return $btn;
}
```

However nothing happens when I click the button with that syntax. Is that due to errors in my suggested code or is it simply impossible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `click` property of the object, not `onclick`, and provide it the reference to the `ClickRefresh` function. Try this:

```
function createRefreshButton() {
    return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh',
        click: ClickRefresh
    });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/04gt30he/)

Comment: I think my problem was that I always tried to add the method name within quotes. This works nicely and is the syntax I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

**Normally I do like this :**

```
function createRefreshButton() {
  // Create button
  var $button = $('<button class="btn_refresh">Refresh Data</button>');

  // Append it
  $('body').append($button);

  // Event for this button 
  $button.on('click',function(){
    alert('Refresh');
  });
}

createRefreshButton();
createRefreshButton();
```

Do not use `id` if not just only one

---

PS : If you have same function for those buttons so :

```
$(document).on('click','.btn_refresh',function(){
   alert('Refresh');
});
```

.. outside `createRefreshButton()`

---

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/xqj9ycLk/1/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had it working, but I was looking to simplify the syntax a bit, like Rory showed in his answer. The snippit I added was for a refresh button. I have only one of those in my code, so no problems with id.

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible**, but you need to change it to the way, jQuery likes:

```
function createRefreshButton() {
    var $btn = $('<button/>', {
        type: 'button',
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh'
    }).click(ClickRefresh);
    return $btn;
}
```

And you should insert the returned value by using either `.append()` or similar. And it works perfectly fine here:

```js
$(function () {
  function ClickRefresh() {
    console.log("Clicked Refresh");
    $("body").append("<br>Clicked Refresh");
  }
  function createRefreshButton() {
    var $btn = $('<button />', {
      type: 'button',
      text: 'Refresh Data',
      id: 'btn_refresh'
    }).click(ClickRefresh);
    return $btn;
  }
  $("body").append(createRefreshButton());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was looking to simplify the syntax a bit, like Rory showed in his answer with the click method call inside the var declaration.

Comment: @Mr.Blonde There's no difference, that's the same thing even I showed, but I answered before Rory. `:)` You can be fair and accept whichever is right. `:)`

Comment: My first syntax snippit is working fine, so my question was if it was possible to have a syntax with the method call inside the var declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor. This will work on dynamically added content as the selector is run at event time (not event-registration time)

```
    $(document).on('click', 'button', ClickRefresh);
```

The add button becomes just this:

```
function createRefreshButton()
{
    var $btn = $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh'
    });
    return $btn;
}
```

Note: ID's need to be unique on a page, so if you want to support multiples, you should distinguish these buttons from any other buttons on the page e.g. using a class:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mybutton', ClickRefresh);

function createRefreshButton()
{
    var $btn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'mybutton',
        text: 'Refresh Data',
    });
    return $btn;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ubmo441a/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had it working, but I was looking to simplify the syntax a bit, like Rory showed in his answer.

Comment: @Mr.Blonde: Using inline click handlers defeats some of the event features of jQuery and should be avoided. When using jQuery always use jQuery handlers, but it's your funeral :)