# Set the position of a dynamically created button

Tags: jquery

I have this code to create a button dynamically:

From **[@Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)**'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613692/creating-buttons-dynamically-using-jquery)

```
function createRefreshButton() {
    return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh',
        click: ClickRefresh
    })
}
$('body').append(createRefreshButton())

function ClickRefresh() {
    alert('refresh');
}
```

How can I set some `CSS` property like : `{position : absolute, top: 50, left : 50}` when creating the button ?

I have tried using  `.css()` like this :

```
function createRefreshButton() {
    return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh',
        click: ClickRefresh
    }).css({position:absolute,top:50,left:50});
}
$('body').append(createRefreshButton())

function ClickRefresh() {
    alert('refresh');
}
```

Without success !

Comment: By using `.css()`?

Comment: Thanks !! Check my edit, i have tried (but certainly in a bad way) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another property to the object used to configure other properties - named `css`:

```js
function createRefreshButton() {
    return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data',
        id: 'btn_refresh',
        css:{position:"absolute",top:"50px",left:"50px"}, // <-- right here
        click: ClickRefresh
    })
}
$('body').append(createRefreshButton())

function ClickRefresh() {
    alert('refresh');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks It's perfect

Answer (score 2):

```js
function createRefreshButton(_top,_left,index) {
    return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Refresh Data'+index,
        id: 'btn_refresh'+index,
        click: ClickRefresh,
         css:{position:"absolute",top:(_top+"px"),left:(_left+"px")},
    })
}
for(var i=0;i<250;i=i+25){
$('body').append(createRefreshButton(i,i,i))
}
function ClickRefresh() {
    alert('refresh');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks !! but i have many button to be created and the position is dinamically created to on a MAP !

Comment: I've edited the code. I hope it will be useful. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT !! For sure it's usefull !